# Doubt about Localization/tf with slam_gmapping and use it for move_base navigation

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have been using slam_gmapping package to have localization frame of my differential robot and use it for the move_base package for path planing. But here I doubt on something about transformation frames which I couldn't see in gmapping tutorials.

Normally there are two things: one is that there is a frame we attach to the system ( this is just a definition), another thing is our estimate of their location and transformation among them. In my system I have the transformations (tf tree)as followed:

/map --> /odom --> /base_link --> /laser_link

I am giving the odometry data to base_link; but after localization there is no newly created localized frame of my robot base. So in which way the move_base navigation package is getting a guess of my robot position as a result of my SLAM node?

I hope I could open my question clearly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45312/doubt-about-localization/tf-with-slam_gmapping-and-use-it-for-move_base-navigation/) by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2012-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the end of the [gmapping](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping) wiki page you can see which tf transformations are required by gmapping and which ones are provided by it.

Essentially, your robot's odometry node should publish the transform between /odom and /base_link while gmapping will publish the transform from /map to /odom. You can then get your robot's pose in map by requesting the transform from /map to /base_link. [this](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) and [this](http://ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) tutorial could be helpful if you didn't find them already.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1